# Compact non-repetitive way for an ALL flag in enums that represent bitflags in C++

Tags: c++, enums, flags, enum-flags, bitflags

I often use enums for bitflags like the following

```
enum EventType {
    NODE_ADDED = 1 << 0,
    NODE_DELETED = 1 << 1,
    LINK_ADDED = 1 << 2,
    LINK_DELETED = 1 << 3,
    IN_PIN_ADDED = 1 << 4,
    IN_PIN_DELETED = 1 << 5,
    IN_PIN_CHANGE = 1 << 6,
    OUT_PIN_ADDED = 1 << 7,
    OUT_PIN_DELETED = 1 << 8,
    OUT_PIN_CHANGE = 1 << 9,

    ALL = NODE_ADDED | NODE_DELETED | ...,
};
```

Is there a clean less repetitive way to define an ALL flag that combines all other flags in an enum? For small enums the above works well, but lets say there are 30 flags in an enum, it gets tedious to do it this way. Does something work (in general) like this

```
ALL = -1
```

?

Comment: Doesn't this tell the compiler that the enum is sizeof(enum) == 8?
I'd like to not work against the compiler if it can optimize it to less space in another way.

Comment: Does `ALL` only want the bits set that have values defined, or can there be bits set that don't have a value associated with them?

Comment: Most optimally, I would this like to be the case, but if the size of the enum is the same as it would be done the manual way (that is automatically deducted), it would be sufficient

Comment: In the specific case shown above, you could use `ALL = (1 << 10) - 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something that'll always cover every other option, like:

```
ALL = 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Or as Swordfish commented, you can flip the bits of an unsigned integer literal:

```
ALL = ~0u
```

---

To answer your comment, you can explicitly tell the compiler what type you want your enum to have:

```
enum EventType : unsigned int
```

Comment: *`0xFFFFFFFF`* – `~0u` or `~0ul` or `~0ull`. Less to write, less to read, less error-prone.

Comment: @Swordfish Both are possible, I like this one better since it more clearly expresses intent for me, I guess that's personal though. Less to read isn't always better.

Comment: But is there a way to let the compiler decide which size the enum should have?

Comment: @PhilippMildenberger The standard says "The underlying type of an enumeration is an integral type that can represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration." so yeah.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Your quote is the perfect reason to answer: So Nay. You control the size of the underlying type of the enum with using either `u`, `ul` or `ull` as suffix to the "match-all" bitmask.

Comment: Isn't it UB to cast a numeric value to an enum with underlying type that is not fixed, when the value is possibly out of range, as in `~0u`?

Comment: @Swordfish So yeah as in "the compiler already decides for you".

Comment: @SombreroChicken You get me wrong. With explicitly sepcifying the thype of the literal YOU tell the compiler which type.

Comment: @zett42 *Isn't it UB to cast a numeric value [...]* – No: [dcl.enum/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#7)

Comment: @zett42 You are referring to unrelated things. There is no cast in `enum { foo = 42uul; };`. [dcl.enum/5.1 ff.](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#5.1)

Comment: You are propably right because this isn't about casting to enum, but declaring an enum.

Answer (score 1):

The root problem here is how may one-bits you need. That depends on the number of enumerators previously. Trying to define `ALL` inside the enum makes that a case of circular logic

Instead, you have to define it outside the enum:

```
const auto ALL = (EventType) ~EventType{};
```

`EventType{}` has sufficient zeroes, `~` turns it into an integral type with enough ones, so you need another cast back to `EventType`